# point of sale application using rails 3

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, button

I am building a point of sale  application using ruby and rails 3.  The user interface is basically one big form that contains the order details: customer, provider, items, etc.  And on submit of the form, the input fields will be used to call various controllers and actions (one form, multiple controllers and actions).

The other part of the application is a panel of buttons.  The buttons correspond to an item (i.e. burger button corresponds to a burger record of class item).  When the button is pushed, the first available line_item field on the order form is populated with the item detail (item name, price).

question 1 & 2: is it practical to have one form in rails 3 to call different controllers and actions with one submit button.  If so, how would I code that?

question 3: how do I code the panel of buttons to populate the order form?

I've been googling this for a while and can't find anything.  Thanks for your help.

Maybe the general question is: How do I make a gui in rails 3 (where buttons call methods)?

Comment: You can't call multiple controllers with one form. I guess you mean "one form, multiple models"? In that case, that should get you started: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#building-a-multi-model-form

Comment: You should accept answers to your old questions (by clicking the green tick) for two reasons: Firstly so that anyone else with the same question knows that the answer was good, and secondly to show users who might answer *this* question that you're likely to give feedback :)

Comment: Gareth: thanks for letting me know about the tick (I'm new to stack overflow)